# How to implement Chalk in Angular cli 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-modules, chalk

So I am building an Angular CLI 6 application and I wanted to implement the Chalk package to have some styling in my console logs.

For testing purposes, I've imported Chalk in my app.component.TS file as follows:

```
import { component } from '@angular/core';
import * as chalk_ from 'chalk';

 @Component({
    //not important 
 })

export class AppComponent {
title = 'My App';

constructor() {
  console.log(chalk.blue('Hello'));
}
```

chalk.blue gives me the error: Property blue does not exist.
When I change that into chalk.default.blue it works and VS code gives me no errors.

When I check the console in the browser I get the error: index.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined.

Can someone help me out with this? I have also tried Colors and I've noticed that all these packages require you to use require() to implement them. But this is ES5 style...

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
```

or

```
var colors = require('colors/safe');
```

Comment: Angular applications execute in the browser. Not in your shell. The console is the browser console, not your terminal. The browser executes the code, not NodeJS.

Comment: You try declaring chalk variable? eg `declare const chalk: any;` Otherwise i don't see where you declare or otherwise get the "chalk" you're calling the `blue` method against.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am just following the instructions as given here: https://github.com/chalk/chalk   << Instead of "const chalk = require('chalk');" I am doing the import as it differs from es5

Answer (score 4):

the above answers are correct, but here is how to get colors in the chrome console

`console.log('%c this is colored', 'color: green; background: red;');`

Comment: I did not downvote you and what you wrote might be working, but I want to use the chalk js package to do this. I am wondering why my implementation of chalk is not working.

Comment: this is the only way to get colors in the browser console that I know of, the other answers are correct chalk only works on nodejs (server-side)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that chalk is for server-side javascript not web/browser(according to process error). You probably need to find another package with similar functionality but for web.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with ES5/CommonJS or ES6+ style, e.g. `require` or `import`. Chalk [doesn't implement browser support](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/issues/1), thus it won't work in Angular or any front-end script code. Chalk 2 even [requires Node.js 4 or later](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/releases/tag/v2.0.0).

As mentioned, you have to use `%c` directive to style your console output in the browser.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Styling_console_output